# How to configure ASP.NET Core static files to change based on Environments (prod vs dev)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a ang2, VS 2015, ASP.NET 4.6.1 project going but it's a non-mvc. So I don't have access to the `<environment>`. Using gulp as well, so that can be used as part of the solution.

How can I configure the static files, like index.html to use the minified version of files? Currently I'm using gulp to do the work.

I took a look at this but it's for MVC projects. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html

**Update**:

Example:

How would I get Index.html in the wooroot folder to point to non-minified scripts in development but then point to minified version in production? Just like in the example in the url. When using MVC you can do  to have it swap out code.   Without MVC it doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: So whats wrong with your Gulp stuff? You mean you have a problem in Gulp or you just want to use something else?

Comment: Gulp is not specific to MVC. It will also work in WebApi Projects and there is no distinction between WebApi and MVC anymore. It's all and the same webstack. The only difference is with or without Razor engine. MVC is nothing more then a router middleware which routes to a specific controller (either an WebApi-esque or one which returns views)

Comment: Sorry gulp doesn't have anything to do with this. Just pointing it out in case it's part of the solution. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer I was looking for.

Using gulp-html-replace, https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace

```
<!-- build:<name> -->
Everything here will be replaced
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Example:

index.html

```
<!-- build:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->

</head>
<body>

<!-- build:js -->
<script src="js/player.js"></script> 
<script src="js/monster.js"></script> 
<script src="js/world.js"></script> 
<!-- endbuild -->
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(htmlreplace({
        'css': 'styles.min.css',
        'js': 'js/bundle.min.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of static files by calling `app.UseStaticFiles` with custom options.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")
    });
}
```

Note that more than one `app.UseStaticFiles` calls may exists. See [Working with Static Files](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html) documentation for more info.